# Do all webcam programs depend on 3D acceleration in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, webcam, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to use my webcam from an Ubuntu virtual guest. 
When I start cheese from a terminal, it tells me that it depends on 3D acceleration. 
Are there alternative ways to test a webcam that don't depend on 3D acceleration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try other webcam software, like [guvcview](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/). Maybe cheese won't work because it has effects which need 3D acceleration.

Comment: thanks. That helps me to verify that the webcam is recognized. BTW I didn't get my webcam working. The blue led goes on and VM freezes the same way as with Windows 7 vm. http://superuser.com/questions/369019/my-virtualbox-virtual-machine-freezes-when-i-try-to-use-the-webcam.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to verify that the webcam is recognized and(or working you can use this webpage http://www.testwebcam.com/